# How to get everything before the hash from the address bar with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, hash

I know I can get the hash value directly with this bit of code:

```
var hash = window.location.hash;
```

But is there anyway I can get the everything before the hash value directly as well?

Thank you!

**Edit Using the Answer bellow**: I am guessing the best way is..

```
var pageAddress = window.location.split('#')[0];
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I use:

```
window.location.href.replace(window.location.hash, '');
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try to subtract the has from the location

Comment: I overlooked the replace method!

Answer (score 1):

This took me 2s to Google:
http://davidwalsh.name/javascript-window-location

You want to take the href and split it on the '#', easy enough to do in JS.

Comment: It doesn't give what he's looking for though.

Comment: And what is he looking for?  "Everything before the hash from the address bar" - that's as clear as mud.

Comment: Well, none of those properties there list `http://davidwalsh.name:80/article.php?s=david+walsh+blog`.

Answer (score 0):

This may or may not be of interest, if you don't mind jQuery (I didn't write it):

jQuery BBQ: Back Button & Query Library:
http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/

Answer (score 0):

Just combine the text before the hash

```
window.location.origin + window.location.pathname + window.location.search
```